# Set select list default value

Tags: forms

I have select list with options:

```
$options = array(0 => '0', 500 => '500', 1000 => '1000');
```

I'm trying to set it's default value to 500:

```
$form['price']['min']['#options'] = $options; 
$form['price']['min']['#default_value'] = 500;
```

But this don't work.

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  The problem was that I was not rendering the form using drupal_get_form(), but some other way because of the use case.

Comment: I met the same question!!!!who can help me?

Comment: 500 should be a '500', string not an integer.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen this problem. That default value should work. I would say try making the key a string and set `#default_value` as a string. The `#options` array may be being passed through `array_merge`  somewhere, thus rekeying integer keys. If keys are strings then that shouldn't happen.
Currently, your array looks like this:

```
$options = array(
  0 => '0',
  500 => '500',
  1000 => '1000',
);
```

But passing that array through `array_merge` can reorganize those integer keys to be in sequential order:

```
$options = array(
  0 => '0',
  1 => '500',
  2 => '1000',
);
```

If that happens then the `500` key simply doesn't exist. This is because `array_merge` does not like to preserve integer keys, but you can use strings to prevent it.
So, I think your array should look more like this:

```
$options = array(
  '0' => '0',
  '500' => '500',
  '1000' => '1000',
);
```

Then you can set your `#default_value`:

```
$form['price']['min']['#default_value'] = '500';
```

Otherwise, is there anywhere else where the `default_value` may be being overridden?

Answer (score 4):

Your code should be work, generally use key value as default value, if it not working make the string as keys and use it as default value.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using a string instead of an integer?

```
$form['price']['min']['#default_value'] = "500"
```

Maybe also worth a try adding the `'und'` key.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the key out of the array $options to define the default value?

`$form['price']['min']['#default_value'] = $options[500];`

Comment: If that is done it will technically just pass the value of $options[500], which is (string) '500'.

Answer (score 1):

```
$options = array(0 => '0', 500 => '500', 1000 => '1000'); 
$form['price'] = array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#options' => $options,
          '#default_value' => 500,
        );
```

In order to set default value in select list we use #default_value parameter. The value of the default_value attribute of the select list would be the key of the select list array.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will show the field with its default value as 500.

```
$options = array(0 => '0', 500 => '500', 1000 => '1000'); 
$form['price'] = array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#options' => $options,
          '#default_value' => 500,
          '#title' => 'Price',
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and I tried giving the index of the array which I want to be the default value and it worked. 
My answer is similar to Ashok KS but his second line I could not understand.

Answer (score -1):

fixed,we should set default value first of that $option array, if we added last,the array key changed [1]=>science,[2]=>drama,the right should be [192]=>science,[231]=>drama:-)

Answer (score -1):

try:

$form['price']['#default_value'] = 500;

It's work good for me.

Answer (score -2):

The `#default_value` should have it's arguments in the form as the `#value`.

```
$form['price']['min']['#default_value'] = $options['500'];
```

Answer (score -4):

Just use

```
$form['price']['min']['#default_value'] = 2
```

which means the default value will take the 2eme option

Answer (score -5):

SOLUTION: Figure out that [form_select_options](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_select_options/6) doesn't handle `#default_value` at all. So I used `#value property`:

```
$form['price']['min']['#value'] = isset($_REQUEST['price']['min']) ? $_REQUEST['price']['min'] : $my_default_value;
```

Comment: Select options do have a default value. Also setting the `#value` param will make it impossible for the user to change the value.

Comment: Look at the code, I set #value to default_value only if there is no any value in #value.

Comment: You always set a value to #value, either `$_REQUEST['price']['min']` or `$my_default_value`. Whatever you put in the #value will be the value of the field regardless of what ever the user inputs.

Comment: If user inputs some value, this value is send through GET ($_REQUEST['price']['min']). So if user inputs value I set #value to user input, otherwise #value = $my_default_value

Comment: That is the problem. Users can use the select, but it wont matter what they select, the result will be the same.

Comment: Indeed, this is not a good idea. There's a reason there are separate keys for value and default_value. I guess it *can* be done in a form builder, but it's certainly incorrect and bad practice.